# Access WCF Project in Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I've ran trough many websites and tried soo many things that I've finally decided to try it creating a question of my own.
This is the error that I get when I try to access my WCF project from my Silverlight 4 app.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this error?

PS. If anyone needs any more information please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx), since your issue is a pure **Cross-Domain** issue.

**P.S:** Cross-Domain file is an XML file indicating which domains can access the service and which can't. One more thing, you can put a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to filter on a deeper level.